# how to take general sales trends into account when forecasting with machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, time-series, random-forest, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast sales of clothing items for a company that has over **500 new items each season**. I've noticed that the **overall sales trend is falling**. I implemented a classic random forest algorithm to forecast sales by item (for example, White T-shirt, Red skirt).

[View dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cu3O.png)

The problem I'm having is that Random Forest **predicts higher values than actual** sales because **it learns from sales history** and doesn't take into account the general sales trend.

[View  Time series image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h7Ol.png)

My question is, isn't there a way to take into account the total sales trend when using machine learning to forecast sales at the article level?

I've tried detrending the total sales history but I don't know how I'll be able to apply this to the sales of individual items.

Comment: Great question; this is really central to ML applications, because it's about merging existing domain knowledge with black box ML. However, it's off topic here, try stats.stackexchange.com or ds.stackexchange.com instead. My first advice is to structure the model according to the components you think are present, and then estimate parameters for that, and just skip the ML altogether -- maybe something as simple as linear regression makes sense here.

Comment: About detrending, this is effectively assuming a linear trend, and then building a black box model for whatever is left over. To make use of it, compute the trend, subtract it, build the model for the leftover part (i.e., residuals), then to get the final output, just add the trend to the black box output.